# to pass email id to ejs templete

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

I am trying to get the email to ejs template but not getting it. How to get the same email saved from mongoose to ejs template
First, I click on the mail icon to send mail to that selected email by nodemailer.

[image]

mailController.js

```
router.get('/donation/mail', async (req,res) => {
  const donations = await Donation.findOne(({_id: id }), {new: true}, (err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log("");
      }

      console.log(doc);
    });
  res.redirect('/', {
    donations
});
});
```

form.ejs

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="To" name="to" value="<%= donations.email %>">
  </div>
```

mailModel.js

```
const donationSchema = new Schema({
   email: {
       type: String
    }

})
module.exports = mongoose.model('donations', donationSchema);
```

error
GET /donation/mail 500 14.818 ms - 2401
Cannot read property 'email' of null

To get that email id from mongoose to ejs template like image

[image]

Comment: Why are you using async/await and a callback? Also ```{new: true}``` isn't necessary here

Comment: I have removed that and tried

Comment: And what was the result? Also in your query where is the ```id``` variable coming from. I'm using a query that looks like this ```const donations = await Donation.findOne({_id:  'someId' })``` and it is working